# Stop window from jumping with movemouseEvent

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5

I have a widget where I want to be able to move the window using the mouse from anywhere inside the widget, except for inside a `qcombobox` or `qlineedit` or `qpushbutton`.

The `mousePressEvent` and `mouseMoveEvent` defined in the `Wizard` init page makes this work.

The problem is that when a `combobox` is clicked, the widget can jump to any location in the screen or the `qcombobox` and `comboboxlist` become separated.

This happens randomly and the results are random.  It can move a few centimeters in any direction or to the bottom left of the screen, bottom right, etc etc.

It only seems to happen when clicking a combo box.

How can I disable the `movemouseevent` for `comboboxes` and `linedits`?

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint, QIODevice, QDateTime, QSize, QObject, QProcess, pyqtSignal, QThread, QEvent, QTimer, QBasicTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QStyle, QWidget, QMainWindow, QCompleter, QProgressBar, QFileDialog, QApplication, qApp, QLineEdit, QLabel, QComboBox, QWizard, QWizardPage, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QShortcut, QMessageBox, QDesktopWidget, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QFont, QIcon, QPixmap, QPalette, QLinearGradient, QColor, QBrush, QCursor


class Wizard(QWizard):
    # Initilisation of the UI and Wizard
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Wizard, self).__init__(parent)

        self.addPage(EnterCode(self))                

        #mos position
        self.oldPos = self.pos()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        delta = QPoint(event.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
        print(delta)
        self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
        # if obj != self.comboBox:
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()


class EnterCode(QWizardPage):
    """ Sensor Code Entry """

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(EnterCode, self).__init__(parent)

        # Spacer Label
        self.spacer = QLabel()

        self._five_digit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.code_combo = QComboBox(self)
        self.label1 = QLabel()

        self.lineedit1 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineedit2 =QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineedit3 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineedit4 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineedit5 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineedit6 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineedit7 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineedit8 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineedit9 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineedit10 = QLineEdit(self)


        self.code_combo_list = [
            'Years', 'Months', 'Weeks', 'Days', 'Hours', 'Years', 'Months', 'Weeks', 'Days', 'Hours']
        for x in self.code_combo_list:
            self.code_combo.addItem(x)

        # num of logs combo box
        self.enter_num_logs = QLineEdit(self)
        self.num_logs_combo = QComboBox(self)
        self.logs_label = QLabel()


        self.num_logs_combo_list = [
            'Years', 'Months', 'Weeks', 'Days', 'Hours', 'Years', 'Months', 'Weeks', 'Days', 'Hours']
        for x in self.num_logs_combo_list:
            self.num_logs_combo.addItem(x)

        # ~buttons
        self.btn = QPushButton('Download Data')

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        layout.addWidget(self.spacer)
        layout.addWidget(self.label1)
        layout.addWidget(self.code_combo)
        layout.addWidget(self._five_digit)

        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit1)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit2)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit3)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit4)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit5)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit6)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit7)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit8)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit9)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit10)


        layout.addWidget(self.logs_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.num_logs_combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.enter_num_logs)

        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.setLayout(layout)



if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem is random it probably happens because when trying to open the popup of the `QComboBox` you press the `QWizard`, so one way to avoid it is to implement a minimum displacement distance using `QApplication.startDragDistance()`.

```
class Wizard(QWizard):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Wizard, self).__init__(parent)
        self.addPage(EnterCode(self))                
        self.oldPos = self.pos()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        delta = QPoint(event.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
        if delta.manhattanLength() > QApplication.startDragDistance():
            self.move(self.pos() + delta)
            self.oldPos = event.globalPos()
```

Comment: The problem still exists, but I think I have found that it happens when the mouse button is clicked too fast in the combobox.

Comment: Or too fast and a slight movement of the mouse... if i hold the mouse in the air and click it does not happen

Comment: @johnashu then a possible approach is to measure time and if it is too fast to move nothing.